# ionic 2:Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

when i run my app in chrome://inspect with this command ionic run android i have this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

[image]

in addition, i tried in android emulator i see also blank page.
just want to notice some things:

**1. in web browser(when i run "ionic serve") and in ionic-view app of ionic 2 i can see the app and it works fine.**

**2.i tried another app and it works fine without any error.**

Answer (score 4):

If you using :

```
let variableName = require("LibraryName");
```

Than remove that and try this :

```
import * as variableName from "LibraryName";
```

or you can read https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/8356 where 'require not defined' also got solved.